# How to stop bundling and publish with CDK Lambda Python (alpha) when no source files are changed

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/README.html#packaging) for the Lambda Python alpha construct says

> Python bundles are only recreated and published when a file in a source directory has changed.

But I am not sure how this works, when I try to deploy without changes to my Lambda
function source file it still is bundling and publishing

```
cdk deploy --require-approval never
...
Step 1/10 : ARG IMAGE=public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.7
Step 2/10 : FROM $IMAGE
latest: Pulling from sam/build-python3.9
e86b34a791fa: Pulling fs layer
9ba3f71dde1f: Pulling fs layer
c09bfc1b1fd5: Pulling fs layer
...
[0%] start: Building 5f67ddad2d5185486f13b5862b7730f02d21b7e9b8cbxxxxx:current_account-eu-west-1
[0%] start: Publishing 5f67ddad2d5185486f13b5868997730f02d21b7e9bxxxxxx:current_account-eu-west-1
[100%] success: Published 0fa75f8b14bfa78ef0ee43368c9d0ea7580c7429e4eafa9fexxxxx:current_account-eu-west-1
```

How can I mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

You will see `Building` and `Publishing` phase output for each asset on each deploy.  As advertised, though, the CDK won't republish unchanged artefacts.  It calls `s3.listObjectsV2` for each asset, skipping the upload if the build hash already exists in the CDK's S3 bucket.

Run `cdk deploy --verbose` to see what's happening under the covers:

```bash
# selected output
MyPythonLambdaStack: deploying...
[0%] start: Publishing cdbcef19c59781e0f77531180a03c2c08316f9307430efda903b9218eb96b0c2:123456789012-us-east-1
[0%] start: Publishing 5c3360714cbfec6dca5b8ac4cb34266ddf97528b3043b9005831289fe4fe3a73:123456789012-us-east-1
[09:49:41] [0%] check: Check s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-123456789012-us-east-1/cdbcef19c59781e0f77531180a03c2c08316f9307430efda903b9218eb96b0c2.zip
[09:49:41] [0%] check: Check s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-123456789012-us-east-1/5c3360714cbfec6dca5b8ac4cb34266ddf97528b3043b9005831289fe4fe3a73.json
[09:49:42] [0%] found: Found s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-123456789012-us-east-1/5c3360714cbfec6dca5b8ac4cb34266ddf97528b3043b9005831289fe4fe3a73.json
[50%] success: Published 5c3360714cbfec6dca5b8ac4cb34266ddf97528b3043b9005831289fe4fe3a73:123456789012-us-east-1
[09:49:42] [50%] found: Found s3://cdk-hnb659fds-assets-123456789012-us-east-1/cdbcef19c59781e0f77531180a03c2c08316f9307430efda903b9218eb96b0c2.zip
[100%] success: Published cdbcef19c59781e0f77531180a03c2c08316f9307430efda903b9218eb96b0c2:123456789012-us-east-1
[09:49:42] MyPythonLambdaStack: checking if we can skip deploy
[09:49:43] MyPythonLambdaStack: skipping deployment (use --force to override)

 ✅  MyPythonLambdaStack (no changes)

✨  Deployment time: 4.18s
```